# solr pattern replacement filter

Tags: regex, solr, solrj

I was trying to write a pattern replacement for solr , half of the filter I have written successfully, I am stuck in one place where I need to preserve some words.

I am writing a pattern replacement filter which will replace everything to null apart from digits and few words like inch , feet , ft .

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^0-9\.\/&&[^\*]]" replacement="" />
```

Here I am successfully able to see convert everything to null apart from digits (22.5, 22/5 , 22 ) to null but how can I add few words here like inch feet , if I am adding inch here it is taking "i n c h" as separate words so its preserving all " i OR n OR c OR h" anywhere in words which I do not want .

I tried putting inside but it did not work.

input - hello world 123.34 123/34 inch pipe

expected output - 123.34 123/34 inch

input - hello this is new 123.34 inch feet

expected output - 123.34 inch feet

Comment: @Emma - I have edited the question

Comment: Are you looking at the stored text or the actual, stored tokens behind the scenes? A `filter` in Solr will only affect the latter part (i.e. what generates the hits), the actually stored text returned _will not change_.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the following expressions would work, yet would be OK to have a look, so that it might give you some ideas, as to how you'd be approaching to solve the problem:

```
(?:[0-9]+(?:[.\/][0-9]+)\s){1,2}(?:inch feet|inch|ft)\b
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/FL5IkN/1/)

```
\b(?!ft|feet|inch)[A-Za-z]+
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/IsmGQn/1/)